# Is there a homomorphism/embedding/isomorphism $F:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ from $\mathcal M$ into $\mathcal N$?

Tags: model-theory

> Let $L=\{R\}$ where $R$ is a binary relation symbol, and let $\mathcal M=(\mathbb Z,\equiv_2)$  and $\mathcal N=(\mathbb Z,\equiv_3)$ be $L$-structures where $m\equiv_2 n \iff 2|m-n$ and $m\equiv_3 n \iff 3|m-n$.
>
> Is there a homomorphism/embedding/isomorphism $F:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ from $\mathcal M$ into $\mathcal N$?

By definition for $F$ to be a homomorphism, it should satisfy:

- For every relation symbol $R$ and $\vec a\in M^n$, we should have $\vec a \in R^{\mathcal M}\implies F(\vec a)=(F(a_1),\cdots,F(a_n))\in R^{\mathcal N}$

So, let $(m,n)\in \mathbb Z^2$,
is there a map $F$ such that $(m,n)\in R^{\mathcal M}\implies F((m,n))=(F(m),F(n))\in R^{\mathcal N}$  ?
i.e is there a map $F$ such that $2|m-n \implies 3|F(m)-F(n)$  ?

Comment: Sure there is a homomorphism: just pick a function where $3|F(m)-F(n)$ always holds... like $F(m)=3m$. Note that you only require one implication, not an equivalence. Now, isomorphisms don’t exist, because the induced partitions are different. Embeddings also exist, I’m afraid; the *only* thing that your $F$ needs to respect is the relation symbol, nothing else. So it can be defined any way you want without regard to any structure in $\mathbb{Z}$ other than the congruence.

Comment: Oh thanks, I understood how there exist a homomorhism and an embedding. Can you please also explain more why isomorphisms do not exist? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: The relation you have is an **equivalence relation** so it induces a partition on the underlying set. Count how many equivalence classes each equivalence relation induces, and verify that an isomorphism would have to preserve the partition.